# Godaddy cron job setup for running php script

Tags: php, linux, cron

can you help me setup cron job on godaddy webhosting? I have php file that i need to run, it is located in cron subdirectory (so address is http://test.com/cron/file.php).
What do i need to write in command input field, so this file is runned?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**NOTE:** GoDaddy has been migrating all hosting packages over to cPanel. The itemized instructions below are for the older GoDaddy interface. The command is still the same.

At the time of this writing, on GoDaddy shared hosting, i could NOT use the following commands: `ping, curl, nc, lynx`

but i COULD use: `wget`

I successfully created a cron job using `wget` to load a PHP file containing a call to `mail()`.

1. log into your GoDaddy account
2. click to expand the "Web Hosting" section and find the server in question
3. click the "Manage" button (it used to be labeled "Launch")
4. on the "Hosting Details" page in "Tools" section, click "Cron Job Manager" button
5. on the "Cron Job Manager" page, click "Create Cron Job" button
6. enter the title you want and select the frequency (1 hour is the most frequent allowed **EDIT:** GoDaddy has added 15-minute increments to the frequency choices.)
7. enter the command below (with your info):

> `wget http://YOUR_DOMAIN/YOUR_PATH/YOUR_PHP_FILE.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

**edit:** as noted by Leandro, this is the method to make a cron job call a remote or local resource -- consult GoDaddy documentation if you want to call a resource locally only (which is also more secure if you're running more sensitive jobs)

in "YOUR_PHP_FILE.php" code all the actions you want to be performed and include a call to `mail()` (or whichever mail method you may want to use assuming you have configured that properly).

By using `mail()` the SMTP relay server will already be set properly in the "php.ini" file to: `relay-hosting.secureserver.net` -- which you can confirm using `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Why you should use this for a localhost script? Directly run the script and avoid security issues.

Comment: (1) locally or remotely not specified by the OP -- (2) additionally, this works for remote calls if you want a site on one server make a request to another server -- (3) this discussion was NOT about security and therefore discussion of security is irrelevant/OFF TOPIC (and certainly not worth more than a comment at worst -- not a downvote) -- (4) downvoting without explanation is contrary to the spirit of stackoverflow

Comment: This answer is not useful for me and  has a lot of inconvenients and lack of research about linux bash that is the way as godaddy uses this procedure. Ill glad to upvote it if the answer is edited in favor of the correct process like other answer provided here.

Comment: And, in any case, this question and answer doesn't belong to SO anyway.

Comment: doesn't matter if it's useful to you -- not the answer your looking for? go elsewhere -- you took pains to downvote a fine answer -- there is not a "correct" procedure -- there is a local and remote method -- remote method works from either/or -- and has worked for many of the upvoters -- you said "Why you should use this for a localhost script?" -- because i DON'T WANT to run the job locally, but on one of my other remote servers -- this is the correct procedure for remote call and to change to your misguided method would be WRONG -- but your bad grammar is a hint to your misunderstanding

Comment: and it's not an issue about whether an answer "belongs" to the OP -- but the OP DEFINITELY determines the scope of the question which in turns affects the scope of the answers -- the guidelines for this site explain to answer and vote on answers based on how it answers the OPs question -- otherwise it's OFF TOPIC

Comment: sorry for my english then :) in any case can't change my vote neither until you edit your question :)

Comment: paste the code for the local method and i'll add it to the answer

Answer (score 10):

```
php_path -q file_name_with_absolute_path

/usr/bin/php -q /home/[user name]/public_html/test.php
```

1: How to know your php_path?

```
echo exec('whereis php');
```

2: How to know absolute path of your file?

```
echo dirname(__FILE__);
```

Comment: This worked on GoDaddy, NameCheap, and a few smaller webhosts as well (except that I used /usr/local/bin/php instead of /usr/bin/php). Also, it gave me confidence that the paths used in the cron statement were all correct. +1

Answer (score 5):

Cron Setup for GoDaddy Shared Hosting Accounts using Cpanel.

*-->>Cron jobs run on GoDaddy's time zone in Arizona. Go Daddy doesn't publish this anywhere.

Example: 
Run cron everyday at 1305 (1:05pm) pacific standard time.

5 14  *  *  *  /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/scriptname.php

Answer (score 3):

Your cron job command should look something like the following (unless your directory structure is different of course):

```
/web/cgi-bin/php5 "$HOME/html/sendy/scheduled.php" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Regrads,

shahana

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Godaddy this should solve your issue.

```
 *  *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/path/to/your/file.php > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

In Godaddy Linux hosting. I used this command to run cron job.

```
/usr/bin/php public_html/now your path
```

Answer (score 1):

Use, for example `CURL` or `wget` or  `lynx`.

```
lynx -s http://link.to/script.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You can setup cron jobs through the Hosting Control Center. Check out GoDaddy's official page here: https://www.godaddy.com/help/create-cron-jobs-3548 for a how-to on setting it up.

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/[user name]/[path to the file]
```

[Reference](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/create-cron-jobs-16086)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a cron job in Godaddy. You can find following command, it will surely help you.

```
php -f /home/[user name]/[path to the file]
```