# How to run cron job for php file in godaddy Cpanel?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am trying to apply cron job in my godaddy cpanel. this is my code:

```
*/5 *   *   *   *   /bin/touch /home/checkforplag/public_html/cron_test.txt >/dev/null 2>&1 && /bin/echo "Cron ran at: `date`" >> /home/checkforplag/public_html/cron_test.txt
```

It's working fine and it insert a line after every five minutes in a text file cron_test.txt. As:

Cron ran at: Fri Dec 16 00:20:01 MST 2016

Cron ran at: Fri Dec 16 00:25:01 MST 2016

Cron ran at: Fri Dec 16 00:30:01 MST 2016

Now when we apply the same on my php file as:

```
*/5 *   *   *   *   /bin/touch /home/checkforplag/public_html/run.php >/dev/null 2>&1 && /bin/echo run.php >> /home/checkforplag/public_html/run.php
```

then it's not working. if it work then it should insert a record in database after every five minutes.

where i am wrong please help me to find out error. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Godaddy cron job setup for running php script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702885/godaddy-cron-job-setup-for-running-php-script)

Answer (score 1):

1. login cpanel
2. open cron jobs menu
3. add Command like 
   curl http://example.com/xyz
4. set cron timing
5. click on button "add new cron job".
6. all done